# How is the Advanced Custom Fields meta_value determined?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to insert custom values via SQL into the wp_postmeta table. This is great, other than when using ACF they need another field inserted alongside.

So if I'm inserting

-- table structure --

`meta_id (PK) | post_id | meta_key | meta_value`

-- values --

`1 | 1 | my_custom_field | Lorem Ipsum`

ACF wants this alongside

`2 | 1 | _my_custom_field | field_57casc5assd`

(i randomly chose `57casc5assd`)

How is the `field_*` value determined? I've tried hashing the field name different ways, but have no luck. If you don't insert this field, `get_fields()` doesn't return the value that I insert manually into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Elliot Condon](https://github.com/elliotcondon) (ACF's author) says in this [support forum post](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/creating-theme-fields-generating-a-key/) that:

> The field_key can be ANYTHING you want but MUST start with field_

So, apparently, you could use any function that provides you a unique ID. ACF is using `uniqid()`.

```
$key = 'field_' . uniqid();
```